# Why doesn't the title and date line up?

Tags: css

Here is a snippet from some generated html I am trying to style.  Why does the date align to the top but the link inside the h3 doesn't?

Using dev tools I can see the link is centrally aligned to the h3 vertically but I cant alter it in any way I have tried with vertical-align or by adjusting height.

```css
article {
  width: 400px;
}
article .date_posted {
  float: right;
  font-size: 12px;
}
article div.thumbnail {
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  float: left;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #fff, 0 0 0 5px red;
  vertical-align: text-top;
}
article div.title h3 {
  display: inline;
}
article div.title h3 a {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: red;
}

article:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div class="uposts-part thumbnail" data-resize="1">
    <img width="288" height="230" src="http://site3.wpmu-subdomain.dev/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2015/10/0f02bd48-7efe-3934-8f4b-093c81560333.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" style="margin-top: -2.5px; height: auto; width: 100%;">
  </div>
  <div class="uposts-part date_posted">
    <span class="date">23</span>, <span class="time">October</span></div>
  <div class="uposts-part title">
    <h3><a href="http://site3.wpmu-subdomain.dev/2015/10/23/dignissimos-deserunt-fugiat-at/" title="Dignissimos deserunt fugiat at sdfsfsd sdfsd s fsdf s ds fds df sdf sdf sd f  sd fsd d">Dignissimos deserunt fugiat at sdfsfsd sdfsd s fsdf s ds fds df sdf sdf sd f  sd fsd d</a></h3>
  </div>
</article>
```

JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xdfc8vnm/

Comment: Consider adding a codepen or jsfiddle to illustrate the problem.

Comment: I don't understand.  There is a blue button on post that says "run code snippet".  You can also copy it to alter it.  Why would duplicating this on jsfiddle make things easier or clearer?

Comment: I'm using iOS stack exchange app and there is no button there to run code. It is also easier to play around in a live editor.

Comment: Ahh OK, https://jsfiddle.net/xdfc8vnm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
article div.title {
  float: left;
  width: 233px;
  line-height: 1
}
article div .title h3 {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
}
article div.title h3 a {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: red;
  display: block;
}
article .date_posted {
  float: right;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

Comment: I understand that If I add padding to the date then that will move it away from the edge but I'd like to try and understand why this is not aligning to the top as there is no margin on the top of the H3 or A tag

Comment: that is because your anchor tag is inline element it generates white space above your text for descenders if you will make it block you can see the difference.

Comment: now this code will work without padding top to the date

Comment: Thanks, I find a lot of CSS things a mystery that cant be explained in the inspector :)

Answer (score 0):

For your class: article .date_posted you need to set same Font Family, Font Size and Font Weight that you used on post title. So it should go like this:

```
article .date_posted {
   float: right;
   font-size: 14px; /* from 12px changed to 14px */
   text-decoration: underline; /* this line added */
   font-family: Lato, sans-serif; /* this line added */
   font-weight: 900; /* this line added */
}
```

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/LddvoLaL/2/

Comment: Your fiddle output has same issue

Comment: You want to bring title and date to the top of body? Maybe I misunderstood question.

Comment: I want to understand why the are not aligned.  Here they have same text size and decoration but the are not aligned.  I am trying to understand why: https://jsfiddle.net/5vx4qnau/